# Вывод переменной через html();

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо вывести пост с помощью `html()`, возникает проблема, выводит это

```
; $('#vk').html(html);
```

видимо где то с кавычкой намудрил

```
 html = "<div id='vk_post_-10639516_65095223'></div><script type='text/javascript'>  (function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = '//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?121'; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'vk_openapi_js'));  (function() {    if (!window.VK || !VK.Widgets || !VK.Widgets.Post || !VK.Widgets.Post('vk_post_-10639516_65095223', -10639516, 65095223, 'bI6jkO3CTgT_zS04pq7BOw1xX3hL', {width: 500})) setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50);  }());</script>";
 $('#vk').html(html);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

тут дело в закрывающем теге `</script>`, который у вас в строке, поэтому надо проэкранировать его. Т.е. должно быть так:

```
   html = "<div id='vk_post_-10639516_65095223'></div><script type='text/javascript'>  (function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = '//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?121'; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'vk_openapi_js'));  (function() {    if (!window.VK || !VK.Widgets || !VK.Widgets.Post || !VK.Widgets.Post('vk_post_-10639516_65095223', -10639516, 65095223, 'bI6jkO3CTgT_zS04pq7BOw1xX3hL', {width: 500})) setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50);  }());<\/script>";
 $('#vk').html(html);
```

Заметьте, в строке, которая присваивается переменной `html`, `</script>` заменен на `<\/script>`